# How to reverse a 3 digit number

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, num1,num2,num3, reverse;    

    printf("Enter the number to reverse:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    num1 = n / 100;
    num2 = (n % 100) / 10;
    num3 = (n % 10) / 100;

    reverse = num3*100+ num2*10;

    printf(" The reverse is %d", reverse);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to reverse a number without using any loops, I included the steps so far, but Im not sure if it is right or not:

1. Declare the int into num1, num2 and num3 along witht the output, reverse
2. Ask the user to enter a number to reverse
3. Store the number using scanf
4. Get the last digit of the number , num1= n/100
5. Get the middle digit from the user, num2=(num%100)/10
6. To get the last digit from the user, num3=(num%10)/100

Are these steps right?
I tried working with the program but no luck whatsoever, until I get the steps correct.

Example:

```
Enter a number: 263
Output: 362
```

The number is always 3 digits, no change whatsoever

Comment: maybe you can show your code.

Comment: is it always a 3 digit number in the input ?

Comment: that can be done recursively. No loop then :)

Comment: last and middle are correct  , first digit = n%10 where n is the number entered by the user

Comment: `reverse = num3, num2, num1;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What is the num in above code ?

Comment: The num is undeclared, it is up to the user to enter any 3 digit number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all , your num3 is wrong  , that is modified below 
   and secondly , reverse is calculated wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{


int n, num1,num2,num3, reverse ;


    printf("Enter the number to reverse:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    num1 = n / 100;
    num2 = (n % 100) / 10;
    num3 = n%10 ;

    // num1 , num2 , num3 are digits only  , to make a number use the below step
    reverse = 100*num3 + 10*num2 + num1;

        printf(" The reverse is %d", reverse);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, my program keeps looping continously

Comment: How ?  there is no loop at all . You can run this code and check

Comment: Oh okay, yes I got it, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using a diverse approach

```
int main()
{
    char string[4];
    int reverse = 0;

    printf("Enter the number to reverse:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &reverse);

    if (reverse > 999)
        return 0;

    sprintf_s(string, "%d", reverse);

    char c1 = string[0];
    string[0] = string[2];
    string[2] = c1;

    reverse = atoi(string);

    printf(" The reverse is %d", reverse);
    return 0;
}
```

or if you don't want to use atoi

```
int main()
{
    char string[4];
    int reverse = 0;

    printf("Enter the number to reverse:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &reverse);

    if (reverse > 999)
        return 0;

    sprintf_s(string, "%d", reverse);

    printf(" The reverse is %c%c%c", string[2], string[1], string[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the middle digit is calculated like

```
num2=(num%100)/10;
```

then the less significant digit is calculated like

```
num3 = (num % 10)/1;
```

or just

```
num3 = num % 10;
```

This statement

```
reverse = num3+ num2+ num1;
```

does not give what you are expecting. You should write instead

```
reverse = 100 * num3 + 10 * num2 + num1;
```

In fact you need not to calculate the digits. Just enter a three-digit number as three separate digits.:)

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n1, n2, n3;

    printf("Enter a three-digit number: ");
    scanf("%1u%1u%1u", &n1, &n2, &n3);

    printf("Reversed number is %u%u%u\n", n3, n2, n1);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a three-digit number: 263
Reversed number is 362
```

If you do not want to output leading zeroes then you can include if statements in your program. That is instead of this statement

```
printf("Reversed number is %u%u%u\n", n3, n2, n1);
```

you can write

```
printf("Reversed number is ");
if (n3) printf("%u", n3);
if (n3 || n2) printf("%u", n2);
printf("%u\n", n1);
```

In this case if to enter for example

```
100
```

then the output will be

```
1
```

instead of

```
001
```

Or you can use the expression `100 * n1 + 10 * n2 + n1`. For example

```
printf("Reversed number is %u\n", 100 * n3 + 10 * n2 + n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, num1,num2,num3, reverse;    

    printf("Enter the number to reverse:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    num1 = n / 100;
    num2 = (n % 100) / 10;
    num3 = (n % 100)%10;

    reverse = num3*100+ num2*10+num1;
    printf(" The reverse is %d", reverse);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.